# Saving Simplistic Android Widget Across Restarts

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a issue that I have been struggling with for some time and its becoming quite frustrating...

I have an app that a user can modify the background image of a widget in a configure activity.  Once they select what image they want I save a SharedPreferences file with the widgetsID and the value for the image... however in the onEnabled of the WidgetProvider I do not know the widget ID, so I can not do a look up of which image to use... Since there can be multiple instances of this widget I do not know which id goes with which onEnabled...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be accomplished simply by:

```
    int[] allids = AppWidgetManager .getInstance(context) .
getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, AwarenessWidget.class));
```

I can get all the IDs of my app and call onupdate and update each ones views based upon the saved preferences

I can elaborate more if anyone needs...

Baffels me no one was able to figure that one out and help me! seems very straight forward now!